# 4K refresh rate is terrible

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have a LG 27UD68P 4K on my MacBook Pro 15" Mid-2015. I can't get it to run on 60 Hz. Its only 30 Hz.

According to this Apple page its possible to get 60Hz. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587

I have tried connecting two cables (Mini DisplayPort -> HDMI) but it still won't work.

What am I doing wrong? Any advice to get this thing at 60Hz would be amazing.

Comment: I don't see anything on the linked page that would say it can do more than 30Hz - unless it's an MST display [which would require Thunderbolt], but the LG page on it doesn't say it is.

Comment: @Tetsujin According to LG it supports 60Hz.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the screen can do - it's what the MacBook can do :/

Comment: There seems to be more websites out there that claim the MBP15 can do 4K @ 60Hz.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with my MacBook Pro 15 Mid-2015 using a single cable: Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort.

The refresh rate is 60Hz - it looks and feels amazing. No jagged and delayed movements anymore.